# Not getting desired output in Flutter Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on kind of book computer application. When gridview creates I want that it will check that selected_computer contains computer id  and Time contains selected_time if contains that means that computer is booked in particular time by other user so that computer can't be booked. But result is not as desired.

My desired output:
if condition is true as shown in the code i dont want to show that computer if condition is false i want to show that computer. but according to data in Firebase Firestore (image provided)computer 1 is booked during '9:00 AM - 9:30 AM' but when other user try to book computer 1 in '9:00 AM - 9:30 AM' time its showing computer 1 but according to code it should not show computer 1. i hope someone in 8b people will help me!

```
  GridView.count(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    mainAxisSpacing: 8,
    crossAxisSpacing: 8,
    childAspectRatio: 1.5,
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    children: computers.map((computer) {
      bool isSelected = selectedComputers.contains(computer.id);
      bool isBooked =
      docs.any((doc) => doc['Selected_Computers'].contains(computer.id) && doc['Time'].contains(widget.selectedtime));

      return GestureDetector(
        onTap: isBooked ? null : () => bookComputer(computer.id),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: isBooked ? Colors.red : computer.isBooked ? Colors.grey : isSelected ? Colors.blue : Colors.white,
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              computer.isBooked ? 'Booked' : 'Computer ${computer.id}',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: computer.isBooked ? Colors.white : isSelected ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }).toList(),
```

In above code I want to check data which is coming from Firebase/Firestore. I'm checking that if selected_computers field contains computer.id and time contains selected time if true than null if false that it will call bookComputer function.

Whole code is below:

[image: FirebaseFirestore Collection]

```
     import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
     import '../components/computer.dart';
     import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
     import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
     import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';

     class CommonZoneScreen extends StatefulWidget {
       List<String> selectedtime = [];
       CommonZoneScreen({Key? key, required this.selectedtime}) : super(key: key);

       @override
      _CommonZoneScreenState createState() => _CommonZoneScreenState();
       }

       class _CommonZoneScreenState extends State<CommonZoneScreen> {
            List<Computer> computers = [];
            List<int> selectedComputers = [];
            final current_user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

           void bookComputer(int id) {
           setState(() {
                 if (selectedComputers.contains(id)) {
                    selectedComputers.remove(id);
                } else {
               selectedComputers.add(id);
            }
          });
          }

         void handleBooking() {
            if (selectedComputers.isEmpty) {
              Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Select Computer", fontSize: 20);
             return;
           }

           FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('CommanZone').add({
             'Email': current_user!.email,
             'Selected_Computers': selectedComputers,
             'Time': widget.selectedtime,
           });

           setState(() {
             selectedComputers.clear();
           });
          }

           @override
             void initState() {
             super.initState();
             for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
             computers.add(Computer(id: i, isBooked: false));
             }
            }

           @override
           Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Comman Zone",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('CommanZone').snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final docs = snapshot.data!.docs;
              return ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: 16),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Common Zone - 20 Group Computers ',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 16),
                  GridView.count(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 8,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 8,
                    childAspectRatio: 1.5,
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    children: computers.map((computer) {
                      bool isSelected = selectedComputers.contains(computer.id);
                      bool isBooked =
                      docs.any((doc) => doc['Selected_Computers'].contains(computer.id) && 
                     doc['Time'].contains(widget.selectedtime));

                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: isBooked ? null : () => bookComputer(computer.id),
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: isBooked ? Colors.red : computer.isBooked ? Colors.grey : 
                           isSelected ? Colors.blue : Colors.white,
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                          ),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                              computer.isBooked ? 'Booked' : 'Computer ${computer.id}',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: computer.isBooked ? Colors.white : isSelected ? 
                     Colors.white : Colors.black,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 16),
                  Text(
                    'Selected Computers: ${selectedComputers.length}',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 16),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: handleBooking,
                    child: Text('Book'),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            } else {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You mention that your output is not as desired, but I don't think you have mentioned what you expected the output to be. Could you add that into the question?

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect? And yes, what's the expected output?

Comment: Sorry sir , I updated my question. you can check out

Comment: "but when other user try to book computer 1 in '9:00 AM - 9:30 AM' time its showing computer 1 but according to code it should not show computer 1" Your code doesn't filter booked computers though, you are just changing color based on that.

Comment: I'd suggest you to clean up your code little bit, then you can see errors clearly.
For example, you have isBooked, but also computer.isBooked. isBooked coming from snapshot but I have no idea on computer objects, where you fetch or parse them. Also putting your firestore methods for fetching/updating into methods should remove duplicates.

Comment: Ok @mirkancal, I want to ask that , Is it good way to check 
docs.any((doc) => doc['Selected_Computers'].contains(computer.id) && doc['Time'].contains(widget.selectedtime));

Comment: Personally, whatever I put in my firestore or db, I'm using DTO to model in the dart side, and then parse them. So I don't play with doc/docs, accesing to maps with []. since it would be error if I write Selected_Comptr instead of Selected_Computers. That part would be booking.selectedComputers or booking.time in my codebase. Resocoder has good videos on ddd and clean architecture on youtube, using firestore as example.